# Showing an activity as a dialog

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

Here is the activity that i want to be a dialog :

```
public class TrainerBookingDialogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_trainer_booking_dialog);

    }



  <activity android:name="com.clearmindai.trainer.module.bookdialog.TrainerBookingDialogActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog"></activity>
```

I'm calling it something like this :

```
  public static  void showBookedDialog(Context context) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TrainerBookingDialogActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
        //show dialog
    }
```

but the error show me this:

> You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this
>   activity.

Comment: Make your activity background as transparent and add a layout where you want to show the UI.

Comment: its showing an error.

Comment: Because you are using AppCompatActivity, with AppCompatActivity you need to use  AppCompat theme. '

Comment: Just change `Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog` to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog`.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
public class MyCustomDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 }
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle s 
 avedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_custom_dialog, container, false); 
   // Do all the stuff to initialize your custom view

    return v;
} 
}
```

please check this link [click here](https://medium.com/@xabaras/creating-a-custom-dialog-with-dialogfragment-f0198dab656d)

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.clearmindai.trainer/com.clearmindai.trainer.module.bookdialog.TrainerBookingDialogActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.clearmindai.trainer.module.bookdialog.TrainerBookingDialogActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Comment: please share full code